# Python's sqlite3 library filled the free space c:\ drive

Tags: python, sqlite, window, storage

I am building a software for a pharmacy to keep track of the pharmacy sales. Iam using VS Code on windows 10 I decided to make a toy data to test the software with. so first I created a table called `sales` in the `sales.sqlite` database file. The table had five columns (`time_stamp: INTEGER`, `medications:REAL`, `beauty:REAL`, `total:REAL`, `user:TEXT`). Then I randomly generated 10000 Unix timestamps and stored them in `timestamps.txt` file in order to load them later. after that I executed the following python code to store my toy data in the sales table in `sales.sqlite` file:

```py
# load the timestamp and store them in a list
with open('timestamps.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    time_stamps = [int(stamp) for stamp in f.read().split('\n')]
# sort the timestamps
time_stamps.sort()

import random 
# generate random values for each variable
medications = [random.randint(100, 5000) for i in range(10000)]
beauty = [random.randint(0, 5000) for i in range(10000)]
total = [medications[i] + beauty[i] for i in range(10000)]
user = [random.choice(['abosoar', 'abosoar1']) for i in range(10000)]

import sqlite3
# create entries by zipping the generated values of each variable
# Iterate over enteries and eatch time store one
for entry in zip(time_stamps, medications, beauty, total, user):
    db = sqlite3.connect('databases\\sales.sqlite')
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO sales (time_stamp, medications, beauty, total, user) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);', entry)
    db.commit()
    c.close()
    db.close()
```

After less than 30 seconds the IDE has crashed and **the free storage of my C:\ drive fall from 2.3+ GB to 79 MB only!!**

I **cleaned temp files by typing `%temp%` and `temp` in the `run` window** but I only restored 200 MB of my free storage.

I used **advanced system care** program to delete junk files but I only restored 500 MB using this method.

I noticed that there is a files called `pagefile.sys` and `hiberfile.sys` that have been modified when the code was running and their sizes are 2.9 GB and 1.6 GB I am wondering if there is any relation between them and the problem.

**There are two problems now:**

1. First: I can't free the space sqlite has taken
2. Second: the software should work in low space PC so the storage problem has to be addressed in order for the software to run.

I hope the above information could help to solve my problem.

Comment: it should be faster to connect only once - before `for`-loop` - and close only once - after `for`-loop

Comment: maybe it makes problem because you connect database and close database in loop - so it may have still older connection in memory. And when it have not enough memory RAM then it moves some RAM on disk - to file `pagefile.sys`.

Comment: maybe instead of generating list like `medications = [random.randint(100, 5000) for i in range(10000)]` you should generate single random value directly in for loop `for entry in zip(time_stamps):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When computer has not enough RAM to keep all running programs and data then it may try to move some information on disk to file `pagefile.sys` - and later it may try to get it back (when programs will need it).

Similar when you turn off computer in `hibernate` mode then it saves RAM in file `hiberfile.sys` to get it back when you restart computer. If you had many data in RAM then it would save many information in `hibernate.sys`.

If you restart computer in normal way (without `hibernate` or `sleep` mode) then maybe it will clear `pagefile.sys` - or you may try to remove it and it should recreate it without alll old data (which it can't get after normal restart).

---

As for me you don't create so much data in this code but maybe your computer has problem with all data created with `[... for i in range(10000)]`. You could use less RAM if you would create single elements directly in main `for`-loop without keeping all in memory.

I runs `for`-loop which keeps in memory only one line from file. It also create only one `medications, beauty, total, user` in every loop.

```
import sqlite3
import random 

# --- before loop ---

db = sqlite3.connect('databases\\sales.sqlite')
c = db.cursor()

# --- loop --- 

for line in open('timestamps.txt'): #, encoding='utf-8'):

    time_stamp = int(line)
    medications = random.randint(100, 5000)
    beauty = random.randint(0, 5000)
    total = medications + beauty
    user = random.choice(['abosoar', 'abosoar1'])

    c.execute('INSERT INTO sales (time_stamp, medications, beauty, total, user) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);', (time_stamp, medications, beauty, total, user)
    db.commit()

# --- after loop ---

c.close()
db.close()
```

Comment: Thank you furas for answering my question..
you answer helped me a lot to fix the issues

Answer (score 0):

As furas said in his answer, the solution is minimize the amount of data in the memory so that it does not backup the data in the `pagefile.sys` file.

Also consider the following post:

https://smallbusiness.chron.com/reduce-pagefilesys-size-53940.html

This provides a fix to this problem (the huge size of `pagefile.sys` file).